# If my app is open or in background i got the notifications. But if i force closed to my app i don't get the notification

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to show the notification to user even app is not running or force closed by user.
If my app is open or in background i got the notifications. But if i force closed to my app i don't get the notification in xcode 8.3 and swift 3 iOS

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            //center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
```

In this way i am registering for notifications

Comment: Yes, force closing an app interrupts lots of standard background behavior (e.g. background `URLSession`, etc.). It's used by users to completely kill an app. This is by design.

Comment: As the _App Programming Guide for iOS_ says, "In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the device before the app can be launched automatically into the background by the system. When password protection is enabled on the device, the system does not launch an app in the background before the user first unlocks the device."

Comment: I solved this. Later on, i figured out that the notification format was not correct. Backend guy wrote wrong format of notification. When we designed notification format according to apple guideline, notification were working fine.